# Convert Geotiff into a NetCDF

Tags: python, netcdf, geotiff, netcdf4

I have tried to convert a Geotiff into a NetCDF and I need to define variables as:

dimensions:

```
 time = None;
 rgb = 3;
 lon = 4886;
 lat = 5462;
```

variables:

```
 image(time,lon, lat, rgb);
```

I am having difficult to define a rgb value to a correspondent lon/lat values in Netcdf format. I am using netcdf4/python, any ideia how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Python and module netCDF4. I am sure you can find several examples of how to write netCDF file with Python.

For example, I started with the examples described here:
http://pordlabs.ucsd.edu/cjiang/python.html

Nevertheless, UNIDATA has its own scripts shown here:
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/simple_xy_wr.py
or some examples here:
http://pyhogs.github.io/intro_netcdf4.html

Regarding the question, I imagine one of the possible variable types could be an integer as the RGB values are from 0 to 255.